Issue with open generic interface while try to get instance using `IServiceProvider` with composition root
Using .NET Core DI container, registered open generic interface with DI container, but while trying to resolve it in 2 different ways to get its corresponding instance keep getting compile exception:

Type or namespace T could not be found

How to resolve it?
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped(typeof(GenericRepository<>));

    services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>),typeof(CachingRepository<>));

    services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), provider =>
        {
            var baseRepository = provider.GetRequiredService<CachingRepository<T>>();
   
            var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            var useCache = configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseCache");

            if (useCache)
            {
                // Getting error: Type or namespace T could not be found
                var cacheRepo = provider.GetRequiredService<ICachingRepository<T>>(); 
            }
            else
            {
                // Getting error: // Type or namespace T could not be found
                var cacheRepo = provider.GetRequiredService(typeof(GenericRepository<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T))); 
            }
        });
}


A compile exception? Strange - but what compile exception exactly? Please copy-paste the message text of that compile exception in your question

@SirRufo the OP wrote the error as comment in the code: "Type or namespace T could not be found"

You can't add open generic types in the way you're doing this. Look into the package Scrutor.

@Hayden, unfortunately, Scrutor will not work here. The OP wishes to decorate an open-generic registration (i.e. GenericRepository<T>) with a generic decorator (CachingRepository<T>). Due to limitations in MS.DI (that Scrutor builds on top), it's impossible for Scrutor to decorate open-generic registrations.

@KlausGütter Sorry, I was confused by "compile exception" - I assumed there has to be more as that posted exception should appear at runtime and not at compile time

@SirRufo, I mentioned 'red wobbly line' as compile exception

You are trying to register a factory delegate, i.e.  provider => { } for an open-generic type IRepository<>. Apart from C# compile error, registering a factory delegate for an open-generic registration is not supported by MS.DI. As a matter of fact, I don't know of any DI Container that actually supports this syntax.
From your code example it seems you wish to decorate GenericRepository<T> conditionally with the CachingRepository<T> decorator. Unfortunately, while using the built-in DI Container (MS.DI) there's no easy fix for this. Even if you apply packages such as Scrutor that plug into MS.DI.
As long as you stick with using MS.DI (plus additional packages) you will have to register every closed implementation of GenericRepository<T> explicitly:
// Register every closed version one by one
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Customer>, GenericRepository<Customer>>();
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Order>, GenericRepository<Order>>();
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Shipment>, GenericRepository<Shipment>>();
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Product>, GenericRepository<Product>>();

// Notice how I only load the config setting once on startup of the application,
// rather than every time a service is resolved.
var configuration = this.Configuration;
var useCache = configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseCache");

if (useCache)
{
    // Here I use Scrutor. Now you can register the open-generic decorator
    // for IRepository<T>, because everything is registered explicitly.
    services.Decorate(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(CachingDecorator<>));
}

If you want to prevent having to manually register all closed repository implementations, you'll have to switch to a different DI Container, such as Autofac or Simple Injector.

registering IRepository for every possible entity in the solution is the not way to go. But, thanks for highlighting & confirming me the DI container limitations w.r.t open generic registration. From solution perspective, I will go with interceptor class like CacheInterceptor which implements IRepository functionalities & intercept every call to repo & check for an entry in cache, on cache miss it forwards the call to DB repo class.
